# combineLatest error from repeat input of valid form values

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, rxjs5, typescript2.0

I have the following:

```
static phones: Map<number, {}> = new Map<number, {}>();
...

  Observable.combineLatest(
        this.form.statusChanges,
        this.form.valueChanges,
        ( status, value ) => ({ status, value }) )
              .debounceTime( 500 )
              .subscribe(
                  ( { status, value } ) => {

                        PhoneComponent.phones.set( this.rowIndex, value );
}
```

When the form becomes valid for the first time, the map values are set with no problems. However, if I should change on value in the form again I get the following exception (PhoneComponent is my custom component in which combineLatest is being used)

```
Angular 2 is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
error_handler.js:47 EXCEPTION: PhoneComponent_1.phones.set is not a function
ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:47
next @ application_ref.js:272
schedulerFn @ async.js:82
SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:223
SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:172
Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
Subject.next @ Subject.js:55
EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:74
NgZone.triggerError @ ng_zone.js:278
onHandleError @ ng_zone.js:257
ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:236
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:157
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:335
data.args.(anonymous function) @ zone.js:970
error_handler.js:52 ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:52
next @ application_ref.js:272
schedulerFn @ async.js:82
SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:223
SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:172
Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
Subject.next @ Subject.js:55
EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:74
NgZone.triggerError @ ng_zone.js:278
onHandleError @ ng_zone.js:257
ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:236
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:157
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:335
data.args.(anonymous function) @ zone.js:970
error_handler.js:53 TypeError: PhoneComponent_1.phones.set is not a function
    at SafeSubscriber.__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2_rxjs__.Observable.combineLatest.debounceTime.subscribe [as _next] (phone.component.ts:137)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:223)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:172)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:125)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
    at DebounceTimeSubscriber.debouncedNext (debounceTime.js:98)
    at AsyncAction.dispatchNext (debounceTime.js:114)
    at AsyncAction._execute (AsyncAction.js:111)
    at AsyncAction.execute (AsyncAction.js:86)
    at AsyncScheduler.flush (AsyncScheduler.js:36)
ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:53
next @ application_ref.js:272
schedulerFn @ async.js:82
SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:223
SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:172
Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
Subject.next @ Subject.js:55
EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:74
NgZone.triggerError @ ng_zone.js:278
onHandleError @ ng_zone.js:257
ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:236
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:157
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:335
data.args.(anonymous function) @ zone.js:970
phone.component.ts:137 Uncaught TypeError: PhoneComponent_1.phones.set is not a function
    at SafeSubscriber.__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2_rxjs__.Observable.combineLatest.debounceTime.subscribe [as _next] (phone.component.ts:137)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:223)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:172)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:125)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
    at DebounceTimeSubscriber.debouncedNext (debounceTime.js:98)
    at AsyncAction.dispatchNext (debounceTime.js:114)
    at AsyncAction._execute (AsyncAction.js:111)
    at AsyncAction.execute (AsyncAction.js:86)
    at AsyncScheduler.flush (AsyncScheduler.js:36)
__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2_rxjs__.Observable.combineLatest.debounceTime.subscribe @ phone.component.ts:137
SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:223
SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:172
Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
DebounceTimeSubscriber.debouncedNext @ debounceTime.js:98
dispatchNext @ debounceTime.js:114
AsyncAction._execute @ AsyncAction.js:111
AsyncAction.execute @ AsyncAction.js:86
AsyncScheduler.flush @ AsyncScheduler.js:36
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:265
onInvokeTask @ ng_zone.js:227
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:264
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:154
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:335
data.args.(anonymous function) @ zone.js:970
```

Comment: Please, provide a plunker with this problem, You can use [this one](http://embed.plnkr.co/w2FVfKlWP72pzXIsfsCU/) as a template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says what's wrong:

> phone.component.ts:137 Uncaught TypeError: PhoneComponent_1.phones.set is not a function

So the problem is not in `combineLatest`.

Your `phones` property is set (it's not `null`) but doesn't have `set` method. `Map.set` should exist so it looks like `phones` is not what you think it is (maybe you override it somewhere unintentionally).

```
class A {
    static m: Map<number, {}> = new Map<number, {}>();
}

A.m.set(1, {'a': 123});
A.m.set(2, {'a': 321});

console.log(A.m);
```

The example above works but have a look where you call the `Observable.combineLatest` because if you look at the compiled JS you'll see that you might call `Observable.combineLatest` before the static properties are initialized:

```
var A = (function () {
    function A() {
    }
    return A;
}());
A.m = new Map();
A.m.set(1, { 'a': 123 });
A.m.set(2, { 'a': 321 });
console.log(A.m);
```

Comment: Thanks. You are correct. I did see the error but still could not figure it out after some time. Another observable was accessing the store and causing the issue. After commenting that, everything ran as expected.